# Facebook Pixel - form submit leads with google tag manager

Tags: facebook, contact-form-7

I use the new facebook pixel to create facebook audiences and measure leads of my facebook campaigns. I integrated the new pixel with google tag manager but my leads are not measured correctly.

My site is a one pagesite on which i use 2 contact forms from contact form 7. After the form submit the contact forms are not redirecting to a "thank you page".

I used the standard facebook pixel and integradet it with google tag manager which works fine for measuring pageviews but the lead function is not working correctly. Do you have any idea to send a lead back to facebook when a form is submitted?

Thx for your help

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
        <script>
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
            n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
            document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

            fbq('init', 'hereismyid');
            fbq('track', 'PageView'); 
            fbq('track', 'Lead');
        </script>

        <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
            src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=hereismyid&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
        /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *on_sent_ok: " fbq('track', 'Lead');"* under additional settings in your contact form and it will work (and remove *fbq('track', 'Lead');* from the original pixel code).

My actual settings:

[image]